# Staging only for Theme Files and Changes

Tags: staging

I have a website which i would like to copy to a staging site. After i made some changes i would like to copy these changes to the live site but ONLY the theme changes. Not any Post or Page Content changes. Any ideas how this can be done easily?

For example: 
site.de (LIVE)
staging.site.de (STAGING)

Copy site.de to staging.site.de
Making changes on staging.site.de (ONLY THEME CHANGES)
Pushing changes to site.de WITHOUT Affecting any Databases.

Thanks

Comment: Then upload only your updated theme files. Do not upload anything else. Add do not dump/import database.

Comment: The customer wants to see the changes on the actuals site. Means i would have to copy the database every time i make changes for him. And i can not be offline, because the customer needs access

Comment: Yes, and every time you need to show your client the changes you made, you will have to only copy theme files to site.de. You don't need to update database.

Comment: No. First he needs to see the changes on the staging.site.de webiste and release the changes. Then i can copy the folder.

Comment: I think I am not able to understand your problem. How are you making changes in theme? From theme editor?

Comment: no. from the FTP directory on the staging.site.de site.

Comment: Are you using different databases on site.de and staging.site.de. Did you created a new database for staging.site.de and import from site.de? If you did that then I don't understand why would your database changes will be transferred from staging.site.de to site.de when you are only uploading theme from staging.site.de to site.de

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17336/discussion-between-max-and-robert-hue).